# gstreamer-critical on executing qt5 on arm

Tags: arm, qt5, gstreamer, qtmultimedia

I have crosscompiled Qt-5.x.x for multimedia support using arm compiler. I was able to build mediaservice plugins using gstreamer. which are:

```
1.libgstaudiodecoder.so
2.libgstcamerabin.so
3.libgstmediacapture.so
4.libgstmediaplayer.so
```

compiled one example using multimedia. tried to execute on board.
Got an error saying:

```
libEGL warning: GLX/DRI2 is not supported
libEGL warning:DRI2:failed to autheniticate 

(exmpl:3830): GStreamer-CRITICAL **:gst_object_ref: assertion 'object != NULL' 
failed
```

UI comes up. But audio is not getting played.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gstreamer plugins missing. install

```
apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```